# R- sapply for standard deviation returns a column of NAs

Tags: r

This may be very basic but, I'm trying to create a column of standard deviations for a variable `Returns_Close_exp`. This variable is actually a numeric vector . So what I want is not the standard deviation of the whole vector, but between two elements.

Here is how I created the vector and how it looks like:

```
 Returns_Close_exp<-diff(log(Data_new$Close_exp), lag=1)
 Returns_Close_exp<-append(Returns_Close_exp,"",0)
 Returns_Close_exp<-as.numeric(Returns_Close_exp)
```

Head of the vector:

```
dput(head(Returns_Close_exp))
c(NA, 0, 0.00121876921624686, -0.00121876921624686, -0.00122025634730871, 
-0.00981602975444584)
```

What I tried to get the standard deviations is:

```
vol_close_exp<-sapply(Returns_Close_exp,sd)
```

But I get a column of NAs.
Does anyone know what is wrong and how to correct it?
Thank you

Comment: You say "So what I want is not the standard deviation of the whole vector, but between two elements." Are you wanting the sd between each two adjacent elements in the vector?

Comment: @duckmayr yes exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do this; using `sapply()` on a vector of indices (essentially as a loop), or using some sort of rolling function, such as with `RcppRoll::roll_sd`:

```r
vec <- c(NA, 0, 0.00121876921624686, -0.00121876921624686, -0.00122025634730871,
         -0.00981602975444584)
# Solution with base R
sapply(1:(length(vec)-1), function(i) sd(c(vec[i], vec[i+1])))
#> [1]          NA 8.61800e-04 1.72360e-03 1.05156e-06 6.07813e-03
# Solution with RcppRoll (recommended when performance is key)
RcppRoll::roll_sd(vec, 2)
#> [1]          NA 8.61800e-04 1.72360e-03 1.05156e-06 6.07813e-03
```

What you were doing initially was applying the function `sd()` to **each** number in your vector, and the `sd()` of a single number is always `NA`.

### Update: Benchmarks

I mentioned `RcppRoll` was recommended when performance is key. Let's see just how much faster the `RcppRoll` solution is:

```r
vec <- c(NA, 0, 0.00121876921624686, -0.00121876921624686, -0.00122025634730871,
         -0.00981602975444584)
# Benchmarks:
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(base = sapply(1:(length(vec)-1), function(i) sd(c(vec[i], vec[i+1]))),
               rcpproll = RcppRoll::roll_sd(vec, 2))
#> Unit: microseconds
#>      expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq       max neval
#>      base 1042.251 1083.269 1264.2698 1133.120 1287.4990 10036.937   100
#>  rcpproll  124.930  133.654  161.4393  145.947  168.3785   286.695   100
#>  cld
#>    b
#>   a
# Let's benchmark with bigger data:
set.seed(123)
vec <- rnorm(1e4)
microbenchmark(base = sapply(1:(length(vec)-1), function(i) sd(c(vec[i], vec[i+1]))),
               rcpproll = RcppRoll::roll_sd(vec, 2))
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>      expr        min          lq       mean      median          uq
#>      base 1966.86067 2063.439484 2141.24892 2134.337090 2198.671640
#>  rcpproll    3.55177    3.701657    4.01187    3.786363    3.904616
#>         max neval cld
#>  2525.95089   100   b
#>    20.71965   100  a
all.equal(sapply(1:(length(vec)-1), function(i) sd(c(vec[i], vec[i+1]))),
          RcppRoll::roll_sd(vec, 2))
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand now. And your solution works.

Comment: @Narjems No problem, glad it helped! I'm about to add some benchmarks too so you can see how much faster the `RcppRoll` solution can be.